# Guardar imagen BLOB en MySQL con Angular

Tags: mysql, nodejs, angular

es posible que alguien me brinde alguna info o dirección url sobre cómo poder llevar acabo la conversion de una imagen mendiante Angular para guardarla en mi base de datos MySQL. Tengo entendido que se puede en un formato BLOB.

front: Angular
back: node - MySQL

Desde ya muchas gracias :)

Comment: Hola, no entiendo bien a que te refieres, pero te pregunto para tratar de abarcar un poco mas. ¿estás tratando de subir una imagen (png, jpg, gif, etc) a un servidor?, ¿pretendes guardar tu imagen directamente en la BD (MySql)?, cualquier inquetud no dudes en preguntar.

Comment: Hola, quisiera guardar una imagen directamente en mi BD MySql, y vi que existe el formato Blob, pero no se como deberia convertir la misma manejado desde angular ya que uso esa tecnología. Soy principiante. capaz puedas hacerme una recomendación con alguna documentación o consejo de su parte de como.
Consideré averiguarme sobre guardar la imagen en el servidor y en la bd guardar ruta de la imagen hosteada, pero luego vi que se podia guardar directamente en la BD haciendo la conversión al tipo del formato blob, pero no he tenido éxito buscando alguna ayuda para ello.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). **¿Podrías compartir el código HTML de la vista con el formulario y el código que usas en el controlador para guardar la imagen en la base de datos?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te recomiendo que en vez de subir la imagen directamente a la base de datos, la conviertas a Base64, ya que con esto estarias conviertiendo la imagen en un String, te adjunto el codigo que yo use y me funciona de 10:

**HTML**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="publicar()" novalidate #f="ngForm">
                <div class="image-container">
                    <label for="image-libro"></label>
                    <input 
                    [(ngModel)]="publicacion.fotoLibro"
                    name="image-libro"
                    (change)="capturarImagen($event)"
                    type="file" 
                    alife-file-to-base64  
                    id="image-libro" 
                    accept="image/png, image/jpeg" 
                    >
                </div>
</form>
```

**TypeScript**

```
    public imagenbase64: string;

    capturarImagen(event: any) {
    const imagenCapturada = event.target.files[0];
    this.extraerBase64(imagenCapturada).then((imagen: any) => {
      this.imagenbase64 = imagen.base;
    });
   }

   extraerBase64 = async ($event: any) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const unsafeImg = window.URL.createObjectURL($event);
        const image = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(unsafeImg);
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL($event);
        reader.onload = () => {
          resolve({
            base: reader.result,
          });
        };
        reader.onerror = (error) => {
          resolve({
            base: null,
          });
        };
      } catch (e) {}
    });
```

Ahora bien, con la funcion extraerBase64 convertis la imagen en formato base64, y con la funcion capturarImagen la cual la implementas en el input,es para que al elegir la imaegn desde el input, corra esta funcion, acapture el archivo, llame a la funcion extrarBase64 y conviereta la imagen a Base64.

Te preguntaras, como hago el envio de ese string base64 a mi DB? te dejo como ejemplo como lo implemente yo usando FormData;

En mi formulario veras que en la etiqueta form, tiene un `(ngSubmit)="publicar()"` , te adjunto la funcion:

**TypeScript**

```
publicar(): void {
    const formData = {
      titulo: this.publicacion.titulo,

      **fotoLibro: this.imagenBase64,**

      autor: this.publicacion.autor,

      anoPublicacion: this.publicacion.anoPublicacion,

      editorial: this.publicacion.editorial,

      genero: this.publicacion.genero,

      numPaginas: this.publicacion.numPaginas,

      sinopsis: this.publicacion.sinopsis,

      resenia: this.publicacion.resenia,
    };
    this.publicacionService.crearPublicacion(formData).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        
        )
        this.router.navigate(['/publicaciones']);
      },
      (err) => {
        alert("Error al publicar");
      }
    );
  }
```

Debes inicializar cada parte de tu modelo en el FormData, pero en donde debes inicializar la imagen, llamas al String imagenBase64, ya que ahi se estara alojando tu imagen en Base64, luego del formData, haces el llamado de tu Service, en mi caso es: `this.publicacionService.crearPublicacion(formData).subscribe();`

Aunque el tema del service depende como lo tengas hecho, en mi casi solo pide 1 argumento.
este seria mi peticion post:

```
public crearPublicacion(publicacion: Publicacion){
    return this.http.post<Publicacion>(`${this.ApiPublicacion}nuevo`, publicacion);
  }
```

Ya si aplicas bien esta informacion, no deberias tener problemas.

Answer (score 2):

Mira, mi recomendación es que no realices almacenamientos de imagenes o archivos de cualquier indole en tu BD, esto porque puede ocurrir una serie de problemas al tratar de almacenarlos:

1. El tiempo de acceso a los archivos es mucho mas lento que desde el Filesystem
2. Incremento en el tamaño de la base de datos (entre mas archivos tengas los backups son mucho mas lentos.
3. Acceso diferido a los archivos, esto ocurre al persistir los archivos en una base de datos, para accederlos siempre se requerirá de un cliente de base de datos que lea el contenido y luego nos lo presente en forma de archivo. En el caso de filesystem podremos acceder directamente a los archivos físicos.
4. Mayor complejidad, dado que la la persistencia en base de datos requiere un mayor conocimiento técnico y más código/procesos/validaciones que en el caso del filesystem.
5. Aumento de los requerimientos de infraestructura: se requiere de mayor memoria RAM, procesador, espacio en disco, etc., requerimientos especificados por el DBMS a ser utilizado en la persistencia de archivos (en la práctica, por lo general ya estamos usando un DBMS para nuestro sistema, por lo que el incremento en infraestructura no suele ser considerable, distinto sería si tuvieramos que considerar implementar persistencia en base de datos en un sistema que no utiliza una base de datos).

Todo esto son los puntos que deberías tener en cuenta al tratar de almacenar información tan compleja en tu base de datos. Por lo que desde mi experiencia lo mejor es que los archivos los almacenes de forma ordenada en tu servidor, por ejemplo:

1. assets/images/company/nike/shoes/season_2019/name_shoe.jpg
2. assets/images/company/tesla/cars/model_2019/tesla_2040.jpg

Esto falicitaría el mantenimiento de tu aplicación en cuanto a recursos del servidor.
**Secuencia lógica**

- Desde tu vista debes crear un `input`de tipo `file`.
- El cliente debe escoger la imagen desde su equipo personal.
- El lenguaje (Angular) debe procesar la imagen.
- Se debe realizar una petición al servidor (PHP, NODEJS, PYTHON, etc) y este recibirá la información obtenida por el cliente.
- Validar si la imagen es valida y no están tratando de enviarnos un archivo malicioso (esto también deberías tenerlo en cuenta en el cliente como una especie de filtro)
- Validar que la carpeta existe y mover el archivo a la carpeta destino.
- Almacenar la dirección de almacenamiento de la imagen en nuestra base de datos.

**Pregunta**

¿Entonces como puedo subir mi archivo al servidor?

**Vista**

```
<input id="file-upload" type="file" (change)="fileSelected($event)">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="subirArchivo()">
    Subir Imagen
</button>
```

**Typescript**

```
  import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

  //Declaracion de interfaces
  interface myData
  {
    mensaje: string;
  };

  //Funcion que procesa un evento para subir archivos al servidor
  fileSelected(event)
  {
    this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
  };

  subirArchivo()
  {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.selectedFile);

    if (this.selectedFile == undefined)
    {
      window.alert("Se debe seleccionar alguna imagen para poder realizar la subida del archivo al servidor.")
      return;
    }
    else
    {
      //Metodo POST 
      this.http.post<myData>('authentication/subirArchivoLogo.php', formData)
      .subscribe(data=>
      {
         //Respuesta del servidor
         console.log("Data: ", data);
      });
    }


  };
```

> **Nota:** Todo esto es solo un pequeño ejemplo de lo que deberías realizar en tu componente Angular. En tu lenguaje de servidor deberías indagar e investigar un poco mas sobre el como lo podrías hacer. Si necesitas algo más, no dudes en preguntar.